# OpenPyXL - How to skip row if cell.value is None

Tags: python, excel, row, openpyxl, skip

I've read plenty of answers here regarding empty rows, but somehow my attempts to adapt those solutions to my script has failed.

I'm reading sheets in excel files using OpenPyXL and loading it's part which is to be processed to DataFrame (first read each row to list of lists and then convert it to DataFrame). The thing is that I'm looking for elegant solution to skip row if the cell.value of the first cell is None

I iterate through rows with the below code:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=adres[0], min_row=adres[1], max_col=adres[2], max_row=adres[3]):
    data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])
```

Comment: The code is incomplete.

Comment: rest of the code is irrelevant because this part is responsible for reading each row cell by cell and place it in list `data_rows`. It's working just fine except I want it to skip rows where first cell row[0] position I guess will be empty.

Comment: You're not necessarily in the best position to decide what's relevant or not. All parameters being passed in should always defined or explained somewhere.

Comment: First of all check solution below, then think: I'm passing coordinates of first and last cell to describe the range to iterate through - it has nothing to do with how to skip row in given range if first cell of row is empty.

Comment: Check the solution I provided? As the maintainer of the library, I know the signature of the method. But when you pass in parameters without additional information you are obscuring the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you,
the solution is so simple I'm ashamed I was even asking :)

Here it is working nicely:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=adres[0], min_row=adres[1], max_col=adres[2], max_row=adres[3]):
    if row[0].value is not None:
        data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])
    else: continue
```

Answer (score 1):

My contribution, maybe can help someone. Considering I am dealing with a bank statement which has 5 columns filled in a row and column A is never empty whether the other columns are not empty as well.

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
    wbook = load_workbook(filename="bank-stat.xlsx")
    sh1 = wbook.active

    #Find the first row empty

    i = 1
    for col in sh1['A']:
        if col.value is not None:
            print(f'Cell A of line {i} is filled' )
            i += 1
    print('First row empty: ',i) 

    wbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably something like what you want:

```
def skip_empty_rows(ws):
    for row in ws.values:
        if row[0] is None:
           continue
        yield row

df = pd.DataFrame((skip_empty_rows(ws))
```